# froala WYSIWYG Editor. I can not put php script

Tags: php, froala

I want to write php script in froala editor, but it becomes a comment.
Do you have any good ideas?
Thank you in advance.

This is

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

It becomes this

```
<!-- <?php echo "test"; ?> -->
```

Comment: show some more code how are you doing it, right now its not clear where is the problem

Comment: I'm no expert but have you created an HTML file (name.html) by any chance? As opposed to a PHP file (name.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to write any PHP code in any WYSIWYG editor that will be executed on the server, for obvious security reasons.

What you probably can do, is to use some obscure syntax with your custom defined keywords (`%%something%%` for example), and then you look for it on the server-side and perform some action when this keyword is encountered, i.e replace it dynamically with something else from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the very late reply! I haven't opened this site for a long time.